# Identify matched rules

Tags: datastage

There are two DB2 tables: **Rule Table** and **Input Table**, which are visually represented in the attached image.
The Rule Table has three rules - **RL001**, **RL002**, and **RL003**.
A rule is considered a match if all conditions within the same **RLID** are mapped.
Our goal is to map the **Input Table** against the rules using DataStage stages to create the **Output Table**.
The **Output Table** will include an additional column, **Match_Rules**.
Is there any out-of-the-box DataStage stages available that can achieve this effect without extensive code writing? If yes, how to achieve it?
Or if we need to use a Java Integration Stage?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is doable although it will be quite some work and it havily depends on the number of differnt rules. It also depends if you will need ony one implementation or a more general solution.

Transforming the input table to a key value pair representation will be beneficial.

Do a lookup against the rules table and use a transformer to check for the rule.
In this transformer you have to build the logic to check if all rules of a rule set have been successfully checked.

This is just a rough guide and it depends on many factors so I cannot provide more details -  hope this helps.